# Room DAO fails to retrieve data from Database

Tags: java, android, android-room, dao

I have a "Contacts" table and a "Phone Numbers" table. The table with the phone numbers includes a row which points to the autogenerated ID of the contact. I try to retrieve all phone numbers linked to that contact in my PhoneNumbersDao, like below:

```
@Dao
public interface PhoneNumberDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(PhoneNumber phoneNumber);

    @Update
    void update(PhoneNumber phoneNumber);

    @Delete
    void delete(PhoneNumber phoneNumber);


    // Retrieve entry/entries by contact ID
    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table WHERE contact_id =:contactId")
    LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getPhoneNumbersById(long contactId);
}
```

My PhoneNumber class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "phone_numbers_table")
public class PhoneNumber implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    /** String resource ID for the phone number */
    @SerializedName("phone_number")
    public String mPhoneNumber;
    /** String resource ID for the phone number type */
    @SerializedName("phone_number_type")
    public String mPhoneNumberType;
    /** String resource ID for the respective contact ID */
    @SerializedName("contact_id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "contact_id")
    public int contactId;

    public PhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, String phoneNumberType, int contactId) {
        this.mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.mPhoneNumberType = phoneNumberType;
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return mPhoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumberType() {
        return mPhoneNumberType;
    }

    public int getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }
}
```

And lastly, I try to access the database using this method in PhoneNumberRepository:

```
public LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getPhoneNumbersByContactId(long id) {
        return phoneNumberDao.getPhoneNumbersById(id);
    }
```

But the method still returns null. Why could that be so?

Comment: 1. Did you put anything in the database? 2. Also, this syntax `WHERE contact_id =:contactId` would be `WHERE contact_id = :contactId`. Don't know if sql will complain or not about the space there but that could be the problem too.

Comment: Where you are observing the LiveData from getPhoneNumbersByContactId() ?

Comment: @sonnet I believe I am adding data to the database's "phone_numbers_table" by using addCallback() when I create the database instance. Using my Samsung phone, I can't access Device File Explorer (apparently it's a security bug with Samsung phones?). Adding a space after the '=' also made no difference..

Comment: @Black4Guy Actually it shouldn't be  LiveData, now that I think about it, since I'm not observing the data anywhere (and even when I retrieve it, I use getValue() to get the list of PhoneNumber objects). It does not harm, right? It's just unecessary?

Comment: No, you cannot get data directly from Live data via getValue() if you are getting data via Room. because the Room takes some time to retrieve data. If you suddenly try to  get from LiveData via getValue() you will always get null. That's why you need to observe data.

Answer (score 0):

Do add this observer in your **Fragment** or  **Activity** via this observer you will be able to get data from the database if you have data in the database otherwise you will get **null**

```
 viewModel.getPhoneNumbersByContactId(contactId).observe(this, new Observer<List<PhoneNumber>>() {
      @Override
      public void onChanged(@Nullable List<PhoneNumber> phoneList) {
//Here you will get all your phone list if you have any in database else you will get null
      }
  });
```

Comment: Hi yes, based on your comment above, I'm not getting that error anymore. Instead, Android won't let me access my database on the main thread, so I should build an AsyncTask method in my repository, to retrieve a list of PhoneNumbers based on input contactId, I believe. Is that plausible?

Comment: Please check this room sample from google    https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view

Comment: She doesn't seem to have an example of retrieving data from the database by using a condition, which is what I need. I have the insert/update/delete async methods, but I'm missing the one I've mentioned. Not sure if I'm not familiar with the framework, but there's few examples of it online..

Comment: I have just asked you go to this like so that you will be familiar with how they are fetching data from the room via Threads

Comment: Ah alright, apologies. So yea I have the other Async methods, I'll just look up how I can create one with a condition (in my case contactId)!

Answer (score 0):

You should have two constructors in your PhoneNumber class, one that takes the id, and another without it with the ignore annotation.Maybe that is the reason the data is not being saved in your databse. So your code should be like

```
@Ignore
 public PhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, String phoneNumberType, int contactId) {
    this.mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.mPhoneNumberType = phoneNumberType;
    this.contactId = contactId;
}

 public PhoneNumber(int id, String phoneNumber, String phoneNumberType, int contactId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.mPhoneNumberType = phoneNumberType;
    this.contactId = contactId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Room required default constructor. So create default constructor in your entity.

```
 public PhoneNumber() {
 }
```